# Android app Math game Crashes

Tags: android, math, crash

I am new to Android Development and I am trying to build an app for a school project. I searched the Internet and found some guides/codes for the Math app that I want to create. I copy/pasted some of them and I managed to create the preferable UI. When I launch the game everything is fine, but when I play the game crashed. The game is about basic mathematical operations. The answers are random (eg. 5x5=?) and the user must answer. If the answer is right a tick appears and when it is wrong a cross appears. When I use the app I manage to enter the answer but when i click enter or C button the app crashes..Any ideas? (I am new to this and I hope I understand what you say to me :P ) Thanks!

Main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_display_message"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.miltos.maths.DisplayMessageActivity">

<include
    android:id="@id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#84b3e7">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/response"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="result"
            android:src="@drawable/tick"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" />





    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#dfeaf1"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="0 + 0"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#dfeaf1"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="= ?"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#dfeaf1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="C"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#86959f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:tag="7"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="#ffcccccc"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#86959f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:tag="8"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="#ffcccccc"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#86959f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:tag="9"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="#ffcccccc"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#86959f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:tag="4"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#ffcccccc"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#86959f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:tag="5"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="#ffcccccc"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#86959f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:tag="6"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="#ffcccccc"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#86959f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:tag="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#ffcccccc"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#86959f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:tag="2"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#ffcccccc"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#86959f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:tag="3"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#ffcccccc"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#86959f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:tag="0"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#ffcccccc"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#86959f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Enter"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener

{
private int level = 0,answer = 0, operator = 0, operand1 = 0, operand2 = 0;
private final int ADD_OPERATOR = 0, SUBTRACT_OPERATOR = 1, MULTIPLY_OPERATOR = 2, DIVIDE_OPERATOR = 3;
private String[] operators = {"+", "-", "x", "/"};
private int[][] levelMax = {
        {10, 25, 50},
        {10, 20, 30},
        {5, 10, 15},
        {10, 50, 100}};
private Random random;
private TextView question, answerTxt;
private ImageView response;
private Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn0, enterBtn, clearBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    question =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
    answerTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
    response =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.response);
    response.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    btn6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    btn7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    btn8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    btn9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn9);
    btn0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn0);
    enterBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);
    clearBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn7.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn8.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn9.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn0.setOnClickListener(this);
    enterBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    clearBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    {
        int passedLevel = extras.getInt("level", -1);
        if(passedLevel>=0) level = passedLevel;
    }

    random = new Random();
    chooseQuestion();
}
private void chooseQuestion(){
    answerTxt.setText("= ?");
    operator = random.nextInt(operators.length);
    operand1 = getOperand();
    operand2 = getOperand();

    if(operator == SUBTRACT_OPERATOR){
        while(operand2>operand1){
            operand1 = getOperand();
            operand2 = getOperand();
        }
    }

    else if(operator==DIVIDE_OPERATOR){
        while((((double)operand1/(double)operand2)%1 > 0) || (operand1==operand2))
        {
            operand1 = getOperand();
            operand2 = getOperand();
        }
    }
    switch(operator)
    {
        case ADD_OPERATOR:
            answer = operand1+operand2;
            break;
        case SUBTRACT_OPERATOR:
            answer = operand1-operand2;
            break;
        case MULTIPLY_OPERATOR:
            answer = operand1*operand2;
            break;
        case DIVIDE_OPERATOR:
            answer = operand1/operand2;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    question.setText(operand1+" "+operators[operator]+" "+operand2);
}
private int getOperand(){
    return random.nextInt(levelMax[operator][level] - levelMax[operator][level] + 1)
            + levelMax[operator][level];

}




@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if(view.getId()==R.id.enter){
        String answerContent = answerTxt.getText().toString();
        if(!answerContent.endsWith("?"))
        {
            int enteredAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answerContent.substring(2));
            if(enteredAnswer==answer){

                response.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick);
                response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            else{
                response.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
                response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            chooseQuestion();
        }

    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.clear){
        answerTxt.setText("= ?");
    }
    else {
        response.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());

    if(answerTxt.getText().toString().endsWith("?"))
        answerTxt.setText("= "+enteredNum);
    else
        answerTxt.append(""+enteredNum);
}
}
```

Error log:

```
01-16 16:04:35.300 4578-4614/com.example.miltos.maths E/EGL_emulation: tid 4614: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
01-16 16:04:37.016 4578-4614/com.example.miltos.maths E/EGL_emulation: tid     4614: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
01-16 16:04:39.157 4578-4578/com.example.miltos.maths E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process:  com.example.miltos.maths, PID: 4578
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                        at com.example.miltos.maths.DisplayMessageActivity.onClick(DisplayMessageActivity.java:156)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Please post your log. You can find it in the bottom of android studio with the name `Android Monitor`. In that select the Error option (Verbose will be default). Then run your app and when it crashes you will get a report

Comment: Post the stack trace of the crash form logcat.

Comment: Thanks for fast answers! error log added @NirmalRaj

Comment: Hope you mean the same that above user means! error log added! @GabeSechan

Comment: can you point out what the 156th line is? just clicking on it will take you there

Comment: @NirmalRaj It's this code:  int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());

Comment: @MiltosTaramanidis you are asking for getTag() not getText(), is this what you want? Because you haven't set a tag - this is why it crashes.

Comment: Why are you using a `getTag()` function without a `setTag()`. I have not gone through your code completely but I think you need to use `getId()` or use `getText()`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I am not sure what I really want because i just pasted the code and did some changes! Although when I use getText it makes me change it to getTextAlignment or getTextDirection and then the toString becomes red asking me to add qualifier

Comment: @NirmalRaj If I use getText (I explain more above ) or getId the toString becomes red  asking me to add qualifier

Comment: replace `int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());` with `int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(question.getText().toString());`

Comment: @W4R10CK Now the app crashes instantly when I press any button (0-10). Before I could press any button and it crashed only when I hit Enter or Clear. Still with your way the same line of code has error

Comment: @MiltosTaramanidis, can u pass me the link where u downloaded this ?

Comment: @W4R10CK sure. It's an old guide and I didn't copy all of that but you will figure it out. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-an-arithmetic-game-setup-and-interface-creation--mobile-18557

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your code

```
btn1.setTag('1');
btn2.setTag('2');
btn3.setTag('3');
btn4.setTag('4');
```

Similarly for all the 10 buttons and try running the same code you have posted.

Comment: tried this for buttons 0-10 but still the same line of code get error! Maybe I need to do something similar for Enter button and Clear button? Because the crash occurs when I press one of them

Answer (score 0):

You have bound your onClick callback function to all buttons, including the `enter` and `clear` button. However, the following line of code, which causes the problem

`int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());`

attempts to get hold of the input in the UI element and assign it to `enteredNum`, which makes perfect sense on input UI elements, but not on the `enter` and `clear` buttons. Therefore, you get a `NullPointerException` since there is no value to be read.

I would propose the following approach. Create e onClick callback and assign them as follows:

- One on your input fields.
- One on your "enter" button.
- One on your "clear" button.

This will make clear that when the `enter` button is clicked, you do not want to read anything of it.

In this way you can separate the business logic of each button. Apart from solving your problem, this will be a good practice for a junior developer.

I would also suggest to start compartmentalizing your code in separate classes, as a generic principle, in order to be more easily to read and especially maintain. An excellent read that covers these principles in its first chapters is [Clean Code by Robert C. Martin](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3735293-clean-code).

Feel free to let me know if your issues on the application persist.